# Show the user name in the layout or prompt level

Tags: bi-publisher

I have user the user name as 'USER1' to login to  BI publisher.is it possible to display my user name like 'USER1' in prompt level or in layout level.i know we have to use 'xdo_user_name' but can any one explain how to use it.please help me thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on an RTF template in BIP.

Put this somewhere in the beginning in your template

```
<?param@begin:XDO_USER_NAME;'Error'?>
```

And then wherever you need to print the username, put:

```
<?$XDO_USER_NAME?>
```

For me, this prints my BIP username in the output.

Comment: One more question can i pass the username to a parameter in BIP to be used?

Comment: You don't have to pass it, it will be passed into the report at runtime. You can use it in your SQL query using :xdo_user_name. you cannot use () function call.

Comment: yes . it worked .i used it in the SQL to create a data set .like 'SELECT :XDO_USER_NAME from dual'